# Why I can't change a model's attribute value while initializing a Rails Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, initialization

Here is a quick question, I have 2 models as follows, when I create a new instance of Question model, its post_type attr is nil.
But when I try that with rails c, I can see that it get value 1, and when I save the model, its value is still nil.
Any explanation?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  POST_QUESTION = 1
end


class Question < Post
  def initialize
    p "post_type=#{@post_type}"

    @post_type = Post::POST_QUESTION
    super

    p "post_type=#{@post_type}"

  end
end
```

Comment: What are you doing in the console to examine the values?

Comment: I added 2 print statements in initialize method (just like in question), and it first prints "post_type=" then "post_type=1".
But when I save the object, it is being saved with nil value for post_type column

Comment: See below, instance variables (`@post_type`) are not the same as ActiveRecord attributes (`o.post_type = ...` and `o.post_type`).

Comment: silly mistake to make it @post_type instead of self.post_type. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails will handle things like this for you with Single Table Inheritance. You need a `"type"` string column in the `posts` table.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
end

class Question < Post
  #...
end
```

Any question you create will be saved to the posts table with type `"Question"`.

Is there a reason you need the post types to be integers?

Anyway, the reason it's not working as you've written it is that all of the model attributes are stored in an instance variable called `@attributes`. While you can use other instance variables once the object is loaded from the database, ActiveRecord won't pay any attention to them.

Comment: thanks for answer.
Sorry I didn't mention, I have a post_type column in posts table.
There is no reason as choosing integer type, it may be string. But that's not the point, I have post_type attr. but even I create a new instance from Question model, its post_type attr is nil, not 1.

Comment: Actually it wasn't because of not having "type" column in table, but I mistakenly wrote that as @post_type instead of self.post_type. And at the end you are right with your last paragraph, rails treats that like different instance variable I guess. thanks!

Comment: Right. I was saying that to use the built-in Single-Table Inheritance, AR expects a "type" column. If you're rolling your own, the way you've done it will work as well.